# How can i add elements into drop down list in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, drop-down-menu

I want to add drop down list with my own values. According to the given drop down list value i am going to do a search particular data. My drop down list should be contained trainer, venue, name and date.

I am working on ruby 1.9.2 and rails 2.3.8 versions and postgresql database adapter. I do not need to retrieve data from database. Drop down list should be contained with my given vales. How can i do this? Anybody plz help me....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add element as follows

Hear I assume there is a model call Entry and it contain two field call :name and :temperature. So I give this example to illustrate drop down menu for select temperature. It may have three values (Hot,Medium,Cold) and this is how we have to write the code

```
<% form_for @entry do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.select :temperature, [['Hot','hot'],['Medium','medium'],['Cold','cold']] %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```